# How to make a bootable recovery partiion(s) for multiple OS? (Linux, Windows...)

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, partitioning, recovery-partition

I'd like to create a recovery entry in my Bootloader (GRUB in this case).

For this I have to create a bootable recovery partition for Linux (say Mint for example) and another for Windows 7 on my drive. I would make a "group" for those two entries named "Recovery" or "Redump".

- Now, I want to know if it is possible to gather recovery partitions in one single extended partition, so that I can economize primary partitions.
- Then, how could I make bootable recovery partition for Linux and Windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows, Ubuntu and "recovery" can be placed on any partition BUT

Windows boot files MUST be on a primary (and active) partition.

So in your system you need only one primary and active partition for Windows boot files.

(On EFI/GPT boot files are on EFI System partition).

For creating Windows Recovery on a separate logical partition you copy the "WinRe.wim" file to that partition and use the tool "ReAgentC.exe" for setting path to .wim file and for activating recovery (e.g. creating entry in Windows BCD and connecting it to main loader).